# Graph diameter of a single vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

Convention-wise, given the simple graph with a single vertex, what is the graph diameter? I can see three options,

- zero, since there is a trivial path from the vertex to itself.
- infinity, since there is no loop joining the vertex to itself.
- undefined, since the graph is connected yet there are no pairs of vertices.

Comment: Actually, I believe that the definition of *diameter* involves the length of the maximal shortest path from any vertex to another. Which would lead me to believe zero is the correct answer.

Comment: @Wayne so the question boils down to, is the trivial path  considered a path in the calculation of the diameter?

Comment: Just my opinion, but a path is traversing a series of edges and the length of a path is the number of edges traversed. How many edges do you cross to go from A to A? Zero. Seems like you don't have to refer to a convention in this case. (Unlike, say, a graph that consists of two, unconnected nodes, where you'd need a convention such as: if no path is possible, the path length is considered to be infinitely long.)

Comment: You seriously think that in graph theory $d(x,x),$ the distance from a point to itself, should be undefined or infinite? Or do you think that $d(x,x)$ should be zero (as with all other distance functions in mathematics) in most cases, but the graph with only one vertex is somhow an exception?